# Cómo reemplazar un valor desde el atributo de otra tabla, inner join, ifnull

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, oracle

Buenas tardes comunidad... me han solicitado extraer desde otra tabla el atributo "equivalente".

Para poner en contexto, existen 2 tablas (en realidad 3 pero con el ejemplo de 2 se entiende)
Tabla1: local, unidadM, nombre, empresa
Tabla2: unidadM, equivalente

Con esto, se genera una lista que se le puede llamar "resultado" con los atributos **local, unidadM y nombre** (pueden ser N), que son mostrados en una tabla.

Ahora el problema... me han solicitado que la **unidadM** ya no será mostrada, y debe ser reemplazada por **equivalente**, vale decir que mediante un inner join con el atributo en común **unidadM** puedo acceder sin problemas. Pero el tema está en que si la **unidadM** no existe en la tabla 2, no puede ser mostrado su **equivalente** y solo se debe mostrar la **unidadM** de la tabla 1. Y al momento de ejecutar la consulta me trae todo, pero cuando no existe lo anterior mencionado no se muestra el registro. ¿Qué podría hacer al respecto?
Estuve pensando en un **ifnull()** pero desconozco eso.

```SQL
SELECT  * FROM tabla1 AS t1 
    inner join tabla3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
    inner join tabla2 t2 on t2.unidadM = t1.unidadM
    WHERE t3.id = 12
    and t1.id = 12
```

La salida actualmente es así en una tabla

Local: 1253 - UnidadM: STR - Nombre: San Fabián

Local: 2355 - UnidadM: STR - Nombre: Antonio

Local: 7535 - UnidadM: QWE - Nombre: Juan

(Después la salida debe ser lo mismo pero en vez de **unidadM**, debe ser con **equivalente**, y si no existe la **unidadM** en la tabla 2, solo mostrar **unidadM** de la tabla 1)

Espero alguna ayuda muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Puedes hacerlo usando un subquery en la columna e IFNULL o CASE, invesiga de aquello, intentas y si no funciona nos indicas tu progreso para ayudarte

Comment: Intenta con un LEFT JOIN a tabla2.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay una consulta suponiendo sólo la existencia de las tablas `tabla1` y `tabla2` (ya que no tenemos detalles de la tercera).

```
SELECT local, nombre, COALESCE(equivalente, tabla1.unidadM)
FROM tabla1 LEFT JOIN tabla2
ON tabla1.unidadM = tabla2.unidadM
```

`COALESCE(x,y)` es una función que devuelve `x` si `x` es no nulo, y `y` si `x` es nulo. El `LEFT JOIN` agrega todos los registros de `tabla1` aún si no hay coincidencias con `tabla2`. Para esos casos donde no hay coincidencias, `equivalente` será nulo y `COALESCE` devolverá `tabla1.unidadM`.